# passing (function) pointers between c and mono

Tags: c, delegates, mono, function-pointers

Hi after refering to http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono
i can call methods from managed code by using mono_runtime_invoke.

Now i want to call a method in the managed code with a function pointer (or at least some pointer) as argument from native c code

managed code

```
public delegate void MyDelegate ();  
//method i want to call from native code  
public static MyDelegate mono_method(MyDelegate c_ptr)  
{  
    //...do sth 
    return c_ptr;  
}
```

native code

```
typedef void (*FUNC_PTR)();   
FUNC_PTR my_fct_ptr = some_c_function;  
//calling the managed method        
MonoObject *result_of_mono_method =  
mono_runtime_invoke(mono_method, NULL, my_fct_ptr, NULL);
```

edit: to point out the problem
how can i call

```
public static unsafe int* mono_method(int *c_ptr)
```

from native c code, without using dllImport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options.
One is to add an internal call that takes a IntPtr (the function pointer) and the arguments: you will then cast the pointer to the function pointer type and call it normally from C code.
Using something like libffi can help to overcome the limitation of having just one function pointer type, it depends how many you need, you didn't specify.

Another option is to use Reflection.Emit to build a dynamic method: in it you will use the calli IL instruction to invoke the function pointer directly.

Comment: i dont get the point in both options where the c pointer goes into c#. Can you maybe write an example or clearify a bit?

Comment: Another option would be to call from the native code a specific C# method that would take an IntPtr and call Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer on it.

Comment: hmm idk if i am getting you wrong. But i dont want to put a mono method on a c function pointer. I only want to call a mono method with a pointer as argument and return value.

Comment: f.e. replace the above managed code method with: public static unsafe int* mono_method(int *c_ptr) and i want to call this method from native c

Comment: Not sure what there is to clarify in my answer: you seem pretty confused, as you also changed the question. Anyway, as for your last change, you can call that method with mono_runtime_invoke(), like with any managed method (there are several examples). This answer likely won't help, since it seems you're mixing up the int* and MyDelegate types, which means that a lot of confusion is going on... I suggest opening a different question with a coherent explanation.

Comment: The question is still how to call a method with a pointer as argument in managed code from native code since the beginning oO Where do you read changes? On the c# side i wouldn´t care if it´s a delegate or a fp if the result can be the same so there´s no mixing up. Well can you show me those several examples? and to clarify your answer, you gave me two options: for what?

Comment: You asked how to call a function pointer passed from C to managed code and mine was an aswer to that. The page you linked to has an example of using mono_runtime_invoke(), see how it calls the Foo method, it's the first example under the "Invoking a method" section.

Comment: No, i asked howto call a method written in c# with a functionpointer as argument from native c code. But i can do another question if it is that unclear. And yes the runtime_invoke from my link works good until i try to pass a pointer instead of an int / string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to ask here, but [this](http://www.huronbox.com/~james/techdemos/cs-callback.html) is the easiest way to do a call back.

Comment: Didn´t see you posted a link because on my screen colors look pretty much even. Well your link is calling c from mono/c# (and i already done that but), i on the other hand need to call mono/c# from c.

Comment: It's doing exactly what you want it to do.  Examine that source very carefully.  It sets a call back into the c code which itself calls back into the c# code.

Comment: It's using function pointers to do that.  The set_cb() he has in there allows the c# code to give the c code a pointer to the function that needs to be called in c#, and the call_cb() function in c calls that c# code.